# Matplotlib: A bug in interactive zooming tool after updating figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am stuck again with interactive plotting with matplotlib.

Everything else works like a charm (hovering and clicking of objects in a figure) but if I zoom the shown figure and it will be updated, zooming rectangle will remain in the new figure. Probably I have to reset zooming settings somehow but I couldn't find out the correct method to do it from other StackOverflow questions (clearing the figure is not obviously enough).

I built a toy example to illustrate the problem. Four points are attached to four images and they are plotted to the figure. With interactive-mode by inserting cursor on top of chosen point, it shows related image in a imagebox. After one point is clicked, program waits 2 seconds and updates the view by rotating all the samples 15 degrees.

The problem occurs when current view is zoomed and then its updated. Zoom-to-rectangle will start automatically and after clicking once anywhere in the figure, the rectangle is gone without doing anything. This is shown in below image. I just want to have normal cursor after figure is updated.

[image]

Here is the code for the toy example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib.offsetbox import OffsetImage, AnnotationBbox
import numpy as np
import copy

def initialize_figure(fignum):
    plt.figure(fignum)
    plt.clf()

def draw_interactive_figures(new_samples, images):
    global new_samples_tmp, images_tmp, offset_image_tmp, image_box_tmp, fig_tmp, x_tmp, y_tmp
    initialize_figure(1)
    plt.ion()
    fig_tmp = plt.gcf()
    images_tmp = copy.deepcopy(images)
    offset_image_tmp = OffsetImage(images_tmp[0,:,:,:])
    image_box_tmp = (40., 40.)
    x_tmp = new_samples[:,0]
    y_tmp = new_samples[:,1]
    new_samples_tmp = copy.deepcopy(new_samples)
    update_plot()

    fig_tmp.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', hover)
    fig_tmp.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', click)
    plt.show()
    fig_tmp.canvas.start_event_loop()
    plt.ioff()

def update_plot():
    global points_tmp, annotationbox_tmp
    ax = plt.gca()
    points_tmp = plt.scatter(*new_samples_tmp.T, s=14, c='b', edgecolor='k')
    annotationbox_tmp = AnnotationBbox(offset_image_tmp, (0,0), xybox=image_box_tmp, xycoords='data', boxcoords='offset points',  pad=0.3,  arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='->'))
    ax.add_artist(annotationbox_tmp)
    annotationbox_tmp.set_visible(False)

def hover(event):
    if points_tmp.contains(event)[0]:
        inds = points_tmp.contains(event)[1]['ind']
        ind = inds[0]
        w,h = fig_tmp.get_size_inches()*fig_tmp.dpi
        ws = (event.x > w/2.)*-1 + (event.x <= w/2.) 
        hs = (event.y > h/2.)*-1 + (event.y <= h/2.)
        annotationbox_tmp.xybox = (image_box_tmp[0]*ws, image_box_tmp[1]*hs)
        annotationbox_tmp.set_visible(True)
        annotationbox_tmp.xy =(x_tmp[ind], y_tmp[ind])
        offset_image_tmp.set_data(images_tmp[ind,:,:])
    else:
        annotationbox_tmp.set_visible(False)
    fig_tmp.canvas.draw_idle()

def click(event):
    if points_tmp.contains(event)[0]:
        inds = points_tmp.contains(event)[1]['ind']
        ind = inds[0]
        initialize_figure(1)
        update_plot()
        plt.scatter(x_tmp[ind], y_tmp[ind], s=20, marker='*', c='y')
        plt.pause(2)
        fig_tmp.canvas.stop_event_loop()
    fig_tmp.canvas.draw_idle()

def main():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(7, 7))

    points = np.array([[1,1],[1,-1],[-1,1],[-1,-1]])
    zero_layer = np.zeros([28,28])
    one_layer = np.ones([28,28])*255
    images = np.array([np.array([zero_layer, zero_layer, one_layer]).astype(np.uint8),np.array([zero_layer, one_layer, zero_layer]).astype(np.uint8),np.array([one_layer, zero_layer, zero_layer]).astype(np.uint8),np.array([one_layer, zero_layer, one_layer]).astype(np.uint8)])
    images = np.transpose(images, (0,3,2,1))
    theta = 0
    delta = 15 * (np.pi/180)
    rotation_matrix = np.array([[np.cos(theta),-np.sin(theta)],[np.sin(theta),np.cos(theta)]])
    while True:
        rotated_points = np.matmul(points, rotation_matrix)
        draw_interactive_figures(rotated_points, images)
        theta += delta
        rotation_matrix = np.array([[np.cos(theta),-np.sin(theta)],[np.sin(theta),np.cos(theta)]])

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wow, so what's the magic behind starting the event loop again? Also, `while True` in an interactive program will most likely always cause trouble.

Comment: So is it enough to start event loop just once? I thought that it should be started after every run and stop it before next update. The original purpose of starting and stopping event loops was to control the blocking effect of plt.show(). If you know much more convenient way to implement this same toy example, I would be very happy because I could use then this same solution to the original program which annotates data points.

Comment: As I see it you should not start the event loop manually and not stop it either. Instead, your program flow can happen within the automatically started event loop. However, I do have problems understanding the desired outcome, which makes it hard to suggest alternatives.

Comment: The outcome of original program is to choose points from the figure and tell to the program, which points should be included and which one should be removed. Hovering and clicking are then essential parts of the program. In addition during the iterations new data points are added to the figure. This kind of action needs interactive mode. When I implemented this solution, I had problems to achieve this kind of behaviour where program waits the response of user before continuing generation of new data points. Is there any other information I could provide for you to solve this error?

Comment: Can this be simplified to just plotting a new dot on screen each time the user clicks? What is the 2 seconds pause used for?

Comment: Actually in the original program and also in this toy example all the previous points change their coordinates so the figure should be cleared. 2 second pause is just added to show that point is clicked. It can be removed without any essential ability of program is lost.

Comment: It looks like that the problem is gone when I remove this pause. The original program does not contain this pause but it has this same bug :S Interesting

Comment: Now I got it. The same bug in the original program could occurs because instead of pause I used input() to ask for the user the label of chosen data point before update ... I have to find out maybe better way to ask label than asking it directly from command prompt...

Comment: New update and follow-up question: It looks like that when zooming mode is used just before updating the picture, it stays also in the updated view. Is it possible to reset navigation toolbar buttons so that none of the modes is selected (or just original view is selected)??

Answer (score 1):

I'm providing you with a starting point here. The following is a script that creates a plot and allows you to add new points by clicking on the axes. For each point one may mouse hover and show a respective image.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.offsetbox import OffsetImage, AnnotationBbox
import numpy as np


class MyInteractivePlotter():
    def __init__(self):
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
        self.ax.set(xlim=(0,1), ylim=(0,1))

        self.points = np.array([[0.5,0.5]]) # will become N x 2 array
        self.images = [np.random.rand(10,10)]

        self.scatter = self.ax.scatter(*self.points.T)
        self.im = OffsetImage(self.images[0], zoom=5)

        self.ab = AnnotationBbox(self.im, (0,0), xybox=(50., 50.), xycoords='data',
                                 boxcoords="offset points",  pad=0.3,  
                                 arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))
        # add it to the axes and make it invisible
        self.ax.add_artist(self.ab)
        self.ab.set_visible(False)

        self.cid = self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect("button_press_event", self.onclick)
        self.hid = self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", self.onhover)

    def add_point(self):
        # Update points (here, we just add a new random point)
        self.points = np.concatenate((self.points, np.random.rand(1,2)), axis=0)
        # For each points there is an image. (Here, we just add a random one)
        self.images.append(np.random.rand(10,10))
        # Update the scatter plot to show the new point
        self.scatter.set_offsets(self.points)


    def onclick(self, event):
        self.add_point()
        self.fig.canvas.draw_idle()

    def onhover(self, event):
        # if the mouse is over the scatter points
        if self.scatter.contains(event)[0]:
            # find out the index within the array from the event
            ind, = self.scatter.contains(event)[1]["ind"]           
            # make annotation box visible
            self.ab.set_visible(True)
            # place it at the position of the hovered scatter point
            self.ab.xy = self.points[ind,:]
            # set the image corresponding to that point
            self.im.set_data(self.images[ind])
        else:
            #if the mouse is not over a scatter point
            self.ab.set_visible(False)
        self.fig.canvas.draw_idle()


m = MyInteractivePlotter()
plt.show()
```

I would suggest you take this and add your functionality into it. Once you stumble upon a problem you can use it to ask for clarifications.